# Please explain why str.index() counts the same letter twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am new to python. I want to get the index (location) of each letter.  I assumed each letter would have its own location, but this code shows other wise.  Obviously I am not doing this correctly.

With this code, can you explain why this `str.index(l)` would double count the same letter.  And how would I properly get the index for each letter? so `"hello`" would be `0,1,2,3,4` and not `0,1,2,2,4` as shown below:

```
>>> def a(str):
    for l in str:
       print(str.index(l))

>>> a('hello')
0
1
2
2
4
>>>
```

Comment: `str.index()` searches for the first occurrence of the substring you provide it. When you loop over your characters and it encounters `l` twice, it will report only the first found index - 2. If you want to get letter index, iterate over your string as: `for index, letter in enumerate(str): ...`

Comment: have you just tried to look up the doc?

Comment: Read the fine documentation—which says it finds the lowest index in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `index` function returns the lowest index for an object (in your case a character) found in a list (in your case a string).

If you wanted to get the index of each letter, you would want to iterate over their indices.

```
for i in range(len(str)):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't write python but it is behaving like indexOf it is returning the first occurrence of that letter in the str

what you wrote is translated to as

```
in this str = "hello"

at this l = "h" that occurs at 0 index,
e = 1
l = 2
l = 2, because of the first occurrence left to right
o = 4
```

looking at the docs i can see.. it can be written like this:

```
def a(str):
  for l in range(len(str)):
      print(l)

a('hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `str.index()` uses the `FAST_SEARCH` algorithm.

`FAST_SEARCH` iterates over a string `s` looking for the 1st occurrence of an individual character `c`.
`str.index()` does this using your full-string as `s`, while iterating over each character which it uses for `c`, one after the other.

This is a good link to see some of the other interesting C stuff going on behind the scenes: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-string-objects-implementation/